# Salesforce Composite Connector Query Limitation

Tags: salesforce, mule

Suppose I'm using the Salesforce Composite Connector in Mule to query 3 different objects in Salesforce, What are the limits to the number of records returned by each query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connector doesn't impose limits. The limits are the ones defined by Salesforce for queries: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm